# Problem evaluating a `sage-shell-mode` function through `ob-sagemath`

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-babel

I'm trying to use `sage-math` within an `org-mode` file. So far I've been able to configure the `sage-shell-mode` package (I'm impressed that `sagemath` can be installed in Debian using the package manager), my configuration:

```
(setq sage-shell:sage-executable "/usr/bin/sage")

(sage-shell:define-alias)
;; Turn on eldoc-mode
(add-hook 'sage-shell-mode-hook #'eldoc-mode)
(add-hook 'sage-shell:sage-mode-hook #'eldoc-mode)

(setq sage-shell:use-prompt-toolkit t)
(setq sage-shell:completion-function 'pcomplete)
```

Then, I installed `ob-sagemath` from the MELPA repository and followed the instructions from its [github page](https://github.com/stakemori/ob-sagemath). Notice that I've added a line requiring the package, that it's not in the instructions... but don't work either!

```
(require 'ob-sagemath)
;; Ob-sagemath supports only evaluating with a session.
(setq org-babel-default-header-args:sage '((:session . t)
                                           (:results . "output")))

;; C-c s for asynchronous evaluating (only for SageMath code blocks).
(with-eval-after-load "org"
  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c s") 'ob-sagemath-execute-async))

;; Do not confirm before evaluation
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)

;; Do not evaluate code blocks when exporting.
(setq org-export-babel-evaluate nil)

;; Show images when opening a file.
(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)

;; Show images after evaluating code blocks.
(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'org-display-inline-images)

(eval-after-load "sage-shell-mode"
  '(sage-shell:define-keys sage-shell-mode-map
     "C-c C-i"  'helm-sage-complete
     "C-c C-h"  'helm-sage-describe-object-at-point
     "M-r"      'helm-sage-command-history
     "C-c o"    'helm-sage-output-history))

(setq sage-shell:input-history-cache-file "~/.emacs.d/.sage_shell_input_history")

(add-hook 'sage-shell-after-prompt-hook #'sage-shell-view-mode)
```

Now, I open an `org-mode` file and try an example:

```
#+begin_src sage :exports both
2+2
#+end_src
```

and I get a comment in the `*Messages*` buffer

> executing Sage code block... ob-sagemath--last-res-info: Invalid
>   output:
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 _emacs_ob_sagemath.read_file_and_run_cell("/tmp/sage_shell_mode7254uF0/sage_shell_mode_temp.sage", filename=None, latex=False, latex_formatter=None)
>
> NameError: name ’_emacs_ob_sagemath’ is not defined

---

#### Complementary info:

From my `.emacs`

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages 
  '((C . t)
    (emacs-lisp . t) 
    (fortran . t)
    (gnuplot . t)
    (ipython . t)
    (latex . t)
    (ledger . t)
    (python . t)
    (mathematica . t)
    (maxima . t)
    (octave . t)
    (org . t)
    (R . t) 
    (shell . t)
))

(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
```

---

### Questions:

- What is happening?
- How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not a problem for you anymore after 2 years, but I had exactly the same problem. I got it working now, and I think the reason was that in my .emacs I was configuring sage-shell-mode (in addition to ob-sagemath), but I didn't have it installed. Installing sage-shell-mode fixed it for me.